# Produce random numbers in matlab without rng shuffle (independent of system time)

Tags: matlab, random

I need to seed random numbers in an array of jobs launching all their own matlab processes. In matlab, they say that using

```
rng shuffle;rand
```

gives different numbers each time, but it turns out this is untrue for arrays where jobs are launched practically at the same time (at least as far as rng is concerned).

how can I get random numbers in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions to your problem:

- If you have a master code which spawns these jobs, have it deal out different seeds to each of the MATLAB processes. This could be as simple as `rng(job_number)`.
- Another way is to use [`feature getpid`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40617-how-to-find-the-process-id-pid-in-matlab) and initialize the seed on the basis of the PID information.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to seed the RNG with any data unique to the process. For instance, if all matlab instances are running on the same machine, you could do the following:

```
rng('shuffle'); % seed with the current time
rngState = rng; % current state of rng

%%% deltaSeed can be any data unique to the process, 
%%% including position in the process queue
deltaSeed = uint32(feature('getpid'));

seed = rngState.Seed + deltaSeed;
rng(seed); % set the rng to use the modified seed
```

which would combine the current time with the process-ID of the matlab instance to generate the seed.

Comment: Note that this option could be fragile if used around midnight when `now` increments by one. Also, seeds, at least for the default random number generator, should be `uint32`.